# Mongoose model schema referencing each other - how to simplify?

Tags: express, mongoose

I am using `mongoose` and have two schemas: `UserSchema` and `CommunitySchema`:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  communities: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: CollectionModel }],
  exCommunities: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: CollectionModel }],
}, { timestamps: true });
```

```
const CommunitySchema = new Schema({
  slug: { type: String, unique: true },
  name: String, 
  description: String, 
  users: [
    { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }
  ]
}, { timestamps: true });
```

User can be a part of multiple `communities` and also leave any community and be in the `exCommunities` field.

When an user joins a community, I have to do a double work: Add the user to a user `community` and update the `community` user field with the reference ID.

Questions:

1. Is there a way to simplify it? For example, by managing the CommunitySchema `users` field automatically based on the UserSchema communities field?

Now I have to do this:

```
   collection.users.push(userId);
   user.communities.push(communityId);
```

Could the collection.users be automatically added when I push a community to user.communities? And how?)

2. Is it possible to add a date when the user is added to a community or leave a community? Something like: `communities: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: CollectionModel, createdAt: "<DATE>" }]`

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you no need to add `communities` and `exCommunities` in UserSchema

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
   name: String,
}, { timestamps: true });

const communityUserSchema = new Schema({
   user_id:{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User"},
   joined_at:{type:Date},
   leaved_at:{type:Date},
   is_active:{type:Boolean},
   role:{type:String, enum:['user','admin'], default:'user'}
});

const CommunitySchema = new Schema({
  slug: { type: String, unique: true },
  name: String, 
  description: String, 
  users:{
    type:[communityUserSchema],
    default:[]
  }
}, { timestamps: true });
```

you can find User's communities by :

```
let user_id = req.user._id;
all_communities = await Community.find({"users.user_id":user_id});

active_communities = await Community.find({"users.user_id":user_id, "is_active":true});

ex_communities = await Community.find({"users.user_id":user_id,"leaved_at":{"$ne":null}});
```

When User Create New Community (create as a Admin):

```
let current_user = {user_id:req.user.id,joined_at:new Date(),is_active:true,role:'admin'};

 //  if you select users from frontend while creating new community  

 let other_user = req.body.user_ids;
 let other_users_mapped = other_user.map((item)=>{ return {user_id:item,joined_at:new Date(),role:'user',is_active:true}}); 

 let all_users = [current_user];
 all_users = all_users.concat(other_users_mapped);

 let community = new Community();
  community.name = req.body.name;
  community.slug = req.body.slug;
  community.description = req.body.description;
  community.users = all_users ;
  let created = await community.save();
```

When User Leave Community :

```
Community.updateOne({_id: community_id , 'users.user_id':user_id },{
   $set:{
       'users.$.is_active':false,
       'users.$.leaved_at':new Date()
   }
});
```

View Community with only active members :

```
let community_id = req.params.community_id;
let data = await Community.findOne({_id:community_id},{ users: { $elemMatch: { is_active: true } } });
```

Comment: This works well! I almost forgot the power of databases :) but what I see is a lot of users in a community.. the CommunityUser is added to the Community instead of creating a separate schema.. so wouldn't it be better to have the CommunityUser as a separate schema and refer to user_id and community_id? Would there be an easy way to keep the reference and access it the same way with `community.users`? 

Comment: also before I could access it with `user.collections`.. is there any easy way to make it work too? I know in postgresql I could do it easily with joined tables but I am not so knowledgable in mongo((

Comment: I asked AI and it solved the problem for me, will provide example and thanks for the help!

Comment: @Petr , it depends on number of users in Community , if there are millions people in Community then you can use separate Collection to store them like `community_id` & `user_id` way . but for small or medium user scale application you can add them in Community Schema . 16MB is the document limit in MongoDB .

Answer (score 0):

AI solved it for me, here is the correct example:

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

interface User {
    name: string;
    email: string;
    communities: Community[];
}

interface Community {
    name: string;
    description: string;
    users: User[];
}

const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    email: String,
}, {
    timestamps: true,
});

const communitySchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    description: String,
}, {
    timestamps: true,
});

// Define the user_communities table using the communitySchema
const userCommunitySchema = new Schema({
    user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    community: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Community' },
    joined_on: Date,
}, {
    timestamps: true,
});

// Use the userCommunitySchema to create the UserCommunity model
const UserCommunity = mongoose.model('UserCommunity', userCommunitySchema);

// Use the userSchema to create the User model, and define a virtual property
// for accessing the user's communities
userSchema.virtual('communities', {
    ref: 'Community',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'user',
    justOne: false,
});

const User = mongoose.model<User>('User', userSchema);

// Use the communitySchema to create the Community model, and define a virtual property
// for accessing the community's users
communitySchema.virtual('users', {
    ref: 'User',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'community',
    justOne: false,
});

const Community = mongoose.model<Community>('Community', communitySchema);
```

The `userSchema` and `communitySchema` are then used to create the `User` and `Community` models, respectively. For the `User` model, a virtual property called communities is defined using the virtual method. This virtual property is used to specify how to populate the `user.communities` property when querying the database. The `communitySchema` also defines a users virtual property, which is used to populate the `community.users` property when querying.